# Solutions to repost categories into multisite blogs?

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, multisite, directory

I have done a search on this topic but was unable to find a solution to this specific question involving wordpress multisite.

I currently have a wordpress network where domain.com is our main site and then each site has been localized with country code domains and also specific country services.

Eg: Main domain.com - Australia domain.com.au - UK domain.co.uk etc

In the back end it is set up as sub directories, domain.com, domain.com/au etc.

What I am looking to do is to set up categories on the main site eg:

Gallery - Australia
              - UK etc

When I tick the box for "Australia" it would automatically repost all posts from the sub category "Australia" into configure/set matching categories?

Is there a plugin/solution to this qeury? Have read a lot of articles but were only meant for single site installations.

Comment: To clarify: You want a post on `domain.com` to also appear on `domain.com.au` if the `Australia` category is selected?

Comment: Hi Pat. Yes. Post on domain.com and it would auto distribute the same post to which ever the category is set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse138563_add_posts' );
function wpse138563_add_posts( $posts ) {
    if( ! is_multisite() ) {
        // if we're not using Multisite, bail
        return;
    }
    if( is_main_site() ) {
        // if we're in the root site, bail
        return;
    }
    $country = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    // This assumes that the categories in your main site
    // have the same names as the country sites do
    if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // alter the main query
        switch_to_blog( BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE );
        $category = get_cat_ID( $country );

        // get the posts with the appropriate category
        $args = array(
            'category' => $category,
        );
        $more_posts = get_posts( $args );
        $posts = array_merge( $posts, $more_posts );

        restore_current_blog();
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Untested. Hopefully this works, or at least provides you a starting point.

**Caveat:** The categories in your root site *must* have the same name as the site names of your subsites for this to work. ie, to have a post show up in a    site named "Australia", your category on `domain.com` must be named "Australia".

#### References

- [`is_main_site()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_site)
- [`is_multisite()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite)
- [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)
- [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog)
- [`the_posts` filter](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_posts?version=3.8&file=wp-includes/query.php)